# error C2065: undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Currently, I have this function inside my other cpp file:

```
  UINT32 functionHtml(const wchar_t *url)
  {
     WinHttpClient client(url);
     client.SendHttpRequest();
     wstring httpResponseHeader = client.GetHttpResponseHeader();
     wstring httpResponse = client.GetHttpResponse();     
     writeToLog(httpResponse.c_str());

     return 0;
  }
```

I have another cpp file, and I would like to execute the stuff inside the above file. Here is the code for the other file:

```
HRESULT CButtonDemoBHO::onDocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *vUrl){
ATLTRACE("CButtonDemoBHO::onDocumentComplete %S\n", vUrl->bstrVal);

//  <---- i would like to call funtionHTML here or ..

if (isMainFrame(pDisp)){
    m_normalPageLoad=false;

//  <---- here..

  MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"Main Document has completed loading", L"Document Complete", MB_OK);

  return S_OK;
 }
 return S_OK;
```

}

I got the error C2065: 'url' : undeclared identifier.
Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to convert vUrl from `VARIANT*` (not familiar with that type) to an object of type `const wchar_t*`, and invoke `functionHtml` on that resulting object. The reason you got an "undeclared identifier" error is that you attempted to invoke `functionHtml(url)`, despite the fact that there is no variable named `url` in the scope in which you are attempting to make that invocation; you need to create your own variable of type `const wchar_t*` to use as a parameter to `functionHtml()`.